# Facebook Home Page in FQL/Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am having issues getting my home page feed in `FQL` in my android application.  It seems to be missing posts when I make the request (generally pictures and a few other things).

Is there something wrong with my `FQL` or is there a limitation with privacy settings?

My end goal is to get the news feed from my profile so I don't really care if it is with `FQL` or `Graph API`, the FQL seemed more straight forward to me since I know `SQL`

EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention that this is in Android SDK (java)

```
 String q = "SELECT post_id, source_id, actor_id, attachment, created_time, target_id, message, app_data, description, permalink FROM stream WHERE filter_key in " +
        "(SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()) AND is_hidden = 0 LIMIT " + limit;
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putString("q", q);
 Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
 Request request = new Request(session,
     "/fql",                         
     params,                         
     HttpMethod.GET,                 
     new Request.Callback(){         
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
             Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());
         }                  
 }); 
 Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a filter or two in your request that might be messing up your results. If you do a Graph API request for "me/home" see what all that gives you. Using the [Graph Explorer API](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) could help in making sure you're getting everything. i think Graph seems to be where Facebook is putting more resources so it might be a good idea to migrate away from FQL if that's an option for you.